# Valgrind shows memory leak with empty main without including headers

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

### **Lubuntu 15.10**

I have project with memory leaks. I can find them, so I cleaned up my main.cpp file, and now it looks like this:

```
int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

When I check memory with the command:

`valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./MyProgram > log1.txt 2>&1`

I got these errors:

```
==5219== 
==5219== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5219==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5219==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5219==      possibly lost: 728 bytes in 18 blocks
==5219==    still reachable: 44,676 bytes in 224 blocks
==5219==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==5219==                         newarray           : 832 bytes in 16 blocks
==5219==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5219== 
==5219== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5219== ERROR SUMMARY: 18 errors from 18 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Some of the errors were:

```
==5219== 2,048 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 240 of 242
==5219==    at 0x402E2EC: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==5219==    by 0x5F7C151: g_realloc (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==5219==    by 0x5F06BCB: g_value_register_transform_func (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==5219==    by 0x5F08D6A: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==5219==    by 0x5ED9A2D: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==5219==    by 0x400EDCF: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==5219==    by 0x400EEDF: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==5219==    by 0x400EEDF: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==5219==    by 0x4000ACE: ??? (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so)

==5219== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 95 of 242
==5219==    at 0x402E0D8: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==5219==    by 0x5F7C0DA: g_malloc0 (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==5219==    by 0x5EFC587: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==5219==    by 0x5F011B8: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==5219==    by 0x5EE929E: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==5219==    by 0x5ED9A1E: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==5219==    by 0x400EDCF: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==5219==    by 0x400EEDF: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==5219==    by 0x400EEDF: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==5219==    by 0x4000ACE: ??? (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so)
```

Full log file: http://pastebin.com/DQxQtnzK

How do I solve this problem? What should I do?

Comment: Add suppressions; they're 'leaks' caused by the startup code that can't be fixed by you and probably won't be fixed by the developers of the C++ runtime.  This is an extensive problem on Mac OS X.  There are typically many allocations and a few tens of kilobytes of memory that are allocated by the startup code.  (Options include `--gen-suppressions=all` and `--suppressions=suppressions-file`.)

Comment: `FATAL: can't open suppressions file "suppressions-file"`

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that your project contains more code than this?

Comment: Read the manual.  You use `--gen-suppressions=all` to generate the suppressions — AFAICR, I've not got that output directly into a file, so I copy'n'paste.  Then edit the file (there's a placeholder where you're supposed to put an ID/name for each suppression entry).  Then you can use the file in subsequent runs with `--suppressions=name-you-created`.  You may need `--show-leak-kinds=all`, and maybe some others, too.  Use `valgrind --help`, but the output is fairly extensive.

Comment: You've linked it with `gobject`. Seems there are static initialization in that library initializing type system

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The leaks are not from your code

<sup>*Transcribing comments with minimal editing.*</sup>

> Add suppressions; they're 'leaks' caused by the startup code that can't be fixed by you and probably won't be fixed by the developers of the C++ runtime. This is an extensive problem on Mac OS X. There are typically many allocations and a few tens of kilobytes of memory that are allocated by the startup code. (Options include `--gen-suppressions=all` and `--suppressions=suppressions-file`.)

This collected the comment:

> FATAL: can't open suppressions file "suppressions-file"

Which got the riposte (since I was under time pressure when I made the comment):

> Read the manual. You use `--gen-suppressions=all` to generate the suppressions […]. Then edit the file (there's a placeholder where you're supposed to put an ID/name for each suppression entry). Then you can use the file in subsequent runs with `--suppressions=name-you-created`. You may need `--show-leak-kinds=all`, and maybe some others, too (`-leak-check=full`, for example). Use `valgrind --help`, but be aware that the output is fairly extensive.

### Worked example — Mac OS X 10.11.4

#### Source (`mincpp.cpp`)

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

#### Compilation

```
g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 mincpp.cpp -o mincpp
```

(I normally use many more warning options, but with this code, there's really no need.)

#### Initial run with `valgrind`

```
$ valgrind mincpp
==69167== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==69167== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==69167== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==69167== Command: mincpp
==69167== 
--69167-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97!
--69167-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 2 times)
--69167-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 4 times)
--69167-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 8 times)
--69167-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 16 times)
--69167-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 32 times)
==69167== 
==69167== HEAP SUMMARY:
==69167==     in use at exit: 22,195 bytes in 190 blocks
==69167==   total heap usage: 255 allocs, 65 frees, 27,947 bytes allocated
==69167== 
==69167== LEAK SUMMARY:
==69167==    definitely lost: 4,120 bytes in 2 blocks
==69167==    indirectly lost: 2,288 bytes in 6 blocks
==69167==      possibly lost: 4,880 bytes in 45 blocks
==69167==    still reachable: 2,344 bytes in 12 blocks
==69167==         suppressed: 8,563 bytes in 125 blocks
==69167== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==69167== 
==69167== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==69167== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
$
```

That's a lot of leakage for such a minimal program!

The unknown `fcntl` messages are a nuisance but appear to be 'mostly harmless'; I probably need to rebuild `valgrind` once more.

#### Generate suppressions

```
$ valgrind --gen-suppressions=all --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all mincpp
==69211== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==69211== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==69211== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==69211== Command: mincpp
==69211== 
--69211-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97!
--69211-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 2 times)
--69211-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 4 times)
--69211-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 8 times)
--69211-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 16 times)
--69211-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 32 times)
==69211== 
==69211== HEAP SUMMARY:
==69211==     in use at exit: 22,195 bytes in 190 blocks
==69211==   total heap usage: 255 allocs, 65 frees, 27,947 bytes allocated
==69211== 
==69211== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 62
==69211==    at 0x1000071FC: malloc_zone_malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:304)
==69211==    by 0x1005DC1E4: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1005E19EB: object_setClass (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1005DABC7: gc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1005DA8C1: preopt_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1005DA5CA: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1005ECC6C: batchFinalizeOnTwoThreads(_malloc_zone_t*, void (*)(auto_zone_cursor*, void (*)(void*, void*), void*), auto_zone_cursor*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x7FFF5FC047CF: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==69211==    by 0x7FFF5FC04516: dyld::registerImageStateBatchChangeHandler(dyld_image_states, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==69211==    by 0x10023789D: dyld_register_image_state_change_handler (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1005D907B: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1001DFC93: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==69211== 
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: reachable
   fun:malloc_zone_malloc
   fun:_read_images
   fun:object_setClass
   fun:gc_init
   fun:preopt_init
   fun:map_images_nolock
   fun:_ZL25batchFinalizeOnTwoThreadsP14_malloc_zone_tPFvP16auto_zone_cursorPFvPvS3_ES3_ES2_m
   fun:_ZN4dyldL18notifyBatchPartialE17dyld_image_statesbPFPKcS0_jPK15dyld_image_infoE
   fun:_ZN4dyld36registerImageStateBatchChangeHandlerE17dyld_image_statesPFPKcS0_jPK15dyld_image_infoE
   fun:dyld_register_image_state_change_handler
   fun:_objc_init
   fun:_os_object_init
}
==69211== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 62
==69211==    at 0x1000071FC: malloc_zone_malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:304)
==69211==    by 0x1005DC1E4: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1005E19EB: object_setClass (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1005DCC96: NXHashInsert (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1005DB9B8: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1005DA5DA: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1005ECC6C: batchFinalizeOnTwoThreads(_malloc_zone_t*, void (*)(auto_zone_cursor*, void (*)(void*, void*), void*), auto_zone_cursor*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x7FFF5FC047CF: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==69211==    by 0x7FFF5FC04516: dyld::registerImageStateBatchChangeHandler(dyld_image_states, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==69211==    by 0x10023789D: dyld_register_image_state_change_handler (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1005D907B: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==69211==    by 0x1001DFC93: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==69211== 
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: reachable
   fun:malloc_zone_malloc
   fun:_read_images
   fun:object_setClass
   fun:NXHashInsert
   fun:_read_images
   fun:map_images_nolock
   fun:_ZL25batchFinalizeOnTwoThreadsP14_malloc_zone_tPFvP16auto_zone_cursorPFvPvS3_ES3_ES2_m
   fun:_ZN4dyldL18notifyBatchPartialE17dyld_image_statesbPFPKcS0_jPK15dyld_image_infoE
   fun:_ZN4dyld36registerImageStateBatchChangeHandlerE17dyld_image_statesPFPKcS0_jPK15dyld_image_infoE
   fun:dyld_register_image_state_change_handler
   fun:_objc_init
   fun:_os_object_init
}
…
==69211== LEAK SUMMARY:
==69211==    definitely lost: 4,120 bytes in 2 blocks
==69211==    indirectly lost: 2,288 bytes in 6 blocks
==69211==      possibly lost: 4,880 bytes in 45 blocks
==69211==    still reachable: 2,344 bytes in 12 blocks
==69211==         suppressed: 8,563 bytes in 125 blocks
==69211== 
==69211== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==69211== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 12)
$
```

Sometimes, I add `--num-callers=NN` for some number *NN*, but the default seems to be 12 on my build (it was less in earlier versions, I think), which is adequate.

#### Generate suppressions in file `min.suppressions`

```
$ valgrind --gen-suppressions=all --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all mincpp 2>./min.suppressions
$
```

#### Edit `min.suppressions`

Delete lines starting `==` and `--`; what's left are suppressions.  Add names for the suppressions.  End result is similar to:

```
{
   Mac-OSX-10.11.4-GCC-5.3.0-C++-Suppressions-001
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: reachable
   fun:malloc_zone_malloc
   fun:_read_images
   fun:object_setClass
   fun:gc_init
   fun:preopt_init
   fun:map_images_nolock
   fun:_ZL25batchFinalizeOnTwoThreadsP14_malloc_zone_tPFvP16auto_zone_cursorPFvPvS3_ES3_ES2_m
   fun:_ZN4dyldL18notifyBatchPartialE17dyld_image_statesbPFPKcS0_jPK15dyld_image_infoE
   fun:_ZN4dyld36registerImageStateBatchChangeHandlerE17dyld_image_statesPFPKcS0_jPK15dyld_image_infoE
   fun:dyld_register_image_state_change_handler
   fun:_objc_init
   fun:_os_object_init
}
{
   Mac-OSX-10.11.4-GCC-5.3.0-C++-Suppressions-002
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: reachable
   fun:malloc_zone_malloc
   fun:_read_images
   fun:object_setClass
   fun:NXHashInsert
   fun:_read_images
   fun:map_images_nolock
   fun:_ZL25batchFinalizeOnTwoThreadsP14_malloc_zone_tPFvP16auto_zone_cursorPFvPvS3_ES3_ES2_m
   fun:_ZN4dyldL18notifyBatchPartialE17dyld_image_statesbPFPKcS0_jPK15dyld_image_infoE
   fun:_ZN4dyld36registerImageStateBatchChangeHandlerE17dyld_image_statesPFPKcS0_jPK15dyld_image_infoE
   fun:dyld_register_image_state_change_handler
   fun:_objc_init
   fun:_os_object_init
}
…
{
   Mac-OSX-10.11.4-GCC-5.3.0-C++-Suppressions-021
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: definite
   fun:malloc_zone_memalign
   fun:_ZL11addSubclassP10objc_classS0_
   fun:_ZL12realizeClassP10objc_class
   fun:_ZL12realizeClassP10objc_class
   fun:_ZN4dyldL12notifySingleE17dyld_image_statesPK11ImageLoader
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListERNS_15UninitedUpwardsE
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader19processInitializersERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListERNS_15UninitedUpwardsE
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader19processInitializersERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListERNS_15UninitedUpwardsE
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader15runInitializersERKNS_11LinkContextERNS_21InitializerTimingListE
   fun:_ZN4dyld24initializeMainExecutableEv
   fun:_ZN4dyld5_mainEPK12macho_headermiPPKcS5_S5_Pm
   fun:_ZN13dyldbootstrap5startEPK12macho_headeriPPKclS2_Pm
}
```

#### Rerun with `--suppressions=./min.suppressions`

```
$ valgrind --suppressions=./min.suppressions mincpp
==72028== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==72028== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==72028== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==72028== Command: mincpp
==72028== 
--72028-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97!
--72028-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 2 times)
--72028-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 4 times)
--72028-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 8 times)
--72028-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 16 times)
--72028-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 32 times)
==72028== 
==72028== HEAP SUMMARY:
==72028==     in use at exit: 22,195 bytes in 190 blocks
==72028==   total heap usage: 255 allocs, 65 frees, 27,947 bytes allocated
==72028== 
==72028== LEAK SUMMARY:
==72028==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==72028==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==72028==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==72028==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==72028==         suppressed: 22,195 bytes in 190 blocks
==72028== 
==72028== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==72028== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
$
```

This shows that the previously reported errors are now suppressed.

Comment: Is it possible that i have a lot of suppressions? I build my project with empty main.cpp. But i have more sources, which i dont include in main.cpp. This is what valgrind generate: http://pastebin.com/8BNeTPeP

Comment: I've had over 200 suppressions in previous versions of Mac OS X and Valgrind — getting them numbered was a nuisance.  I got to 21 with the minimal program.  What's your definition of a lot?  (I've not gone chasing your link yet — there's this 'work' thingy I'm supposed to be doing.)

Comment: I forget to tell, i have lubuntu 15.10 if it matters

Comment: The principles remain the same; the details are bound to be radically different from Mac OS X.  That is, the suppressions I show are relevant on Mac, irrelevant on Ubuntu.  Anything you showed from Ubuntu would be irrelevant on Mac.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Comment: Heap summary is still come from nowhere, any way to remove it?

Comment: I don’t know of a way to remove the heap summary, @TomSawyer.