# Valgrind showing tons of memory leaks on blank program

Tags: c, macos, valgrind

I'm trying to learn how to use valgrind, and so I have written the following program:

```
// no imports in the program either
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

To the best of my knowledge, this should leak any memory and so I should get a response from valgrind indicating that. However, here is what valgrind shows:

```
$ gcc strings.c -o strings.out && valgrind ./strings.out

==49859== HEAP SUMMARY:
==49859==     in use at exit: 19,158 bytes in 165 blocks
==49859==   total heap usage: 186 allocs, 21 frees, 27,606 bytes allocated
==49859== 
==49859== LEAK SUMMARY:
==49859==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==49859==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==49859==      possibly lost: 8,840 bytes in 7 blocks
==49859==    still reachable: 10,318 bytes in 158 blocks
==49859==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

A few questions on this:

- Why does it say 19,158 bytes used at the end? My thought was there should be zero bytes at the end since I haven't even defined anything.
- What does the 49859 mean at the left?
- Finally, where does the `186 allocs, 21 frees, 27,606 bytes allocated` come from?

**Update:**

This seems to be a Mac-centric error and in Google seems to be quite common on newer version of OSX. Running the same thing on ubuntu seemed fine:

```
==5689== Command: ./main.out
==5689== 
Hello
==5689== 
==5689== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5689==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5689==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==5689== 
==5689== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5689== 
==5689== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5689== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: libc – the thing that gives you `printf` and `main` – does a lot of stuff in the background. Also note that just using memory at exit doesn’t mean you have a leak (see the leak summary, with no definite losses reported).

Comment: The *"suppression"* files shipped with `valgrind` that mask system allocated memory generally only mask libc well on Linux (and they don't completely do that any more). There are instructions for generating new suppression files (the second type for memcheck) in the actual `valgrind` manual, e.g. [Writing suppression files](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.suppfiles). `valgrind` used to mask 100% of system allocations (version 3.12.0 does), but later versions do not.

Comment: That's more or less normal for a Mac.  The startup code allocates a lot of memory that is not freed on exit.  You never get 'all memory freed' like you can on Linux.  See, for example, [Valgrind shows memory leak with empty main without including headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893494/valgrind-shows-memory-leak-with-empty-main-without-including-headers)