# Valgrind strange memory leak

Tags: c, macos, valgrind, clion

When I launch valgrind on my small program I get a very strange memory leak that I don't understand. None of my coding files are mentioned in the report.

Here is the report :

```
==6063==     in use at exit: 17,759 bytes in 159 blocks
==6063==   total heap usage: 178 allocs, 19 frees, 26,635 bytes allocated
==6063== 
==6063== 2,048 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 34 of 37
==6063==    at 0x100123545: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-6049595/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==6063==    by 0x100701E95: class_setWeakIvarLayout (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==6063==    by 0x100701E26: class_setWeakIvarLayout (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==6063==    by 0x100705BF9: _objc_atfork_parent (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==6063==    by 0x1006F3742: property_copyAttributeList (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==6063==    by 0x1006E91E7: NXMapRemove (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==6063==    by 0x1006FBBD2: attachCategories(objc_class*, locstamped_category_t const*, unsigned int, int) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==6063==    by 0x1006FB6C6: objc_class::mangledName() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==6063==    by 0x1006FB69F: objc_class::mangledName() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==6063==    by 0x1006FB69F: objc_class::mangledName() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==6063==    by 0x1006FB69F: objc_class::mangledName() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==6063==    by 0x1006E7406: objc_opt::objc_stringhash_t::getIndex(char const*) const (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==6063== 
==6063== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6063==    definitely lost: 2,048 bytes in 1 blocks
==6063==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6063==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6063==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6063==         suppressed: 15,711 bytes in 158 blocks
==6063== 
==6063== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==6063== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 7 from 7)
```

These are my project files : [image]

And this is my main :

```
int main() {
    char** tab = allouer_tab_2D(3,4);
    afficher_tab_2D(tab, 3, 4);
    desallouer_tab_2D(tab, 3);
    int col = 0;
    int lig = 0;
    taille_fichier("../tabCaracteres.txt",&lig,&col);
    printf("Lignes : %d, Colonnes : %d", lig, col);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my fonctions_fichiers.c (sorry for the french) :

```
#include "fonctions_fichiers.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char** allouer_tab_2D(int n, int m){
    char** tab = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        tab[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(char));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            tab[i][j] = 'a';
        }
    }
    return tab;
}

void desallouer_tab_2D(char** tab, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        free(tab[i]);
    }
    free(tab);
}

void afficher_tab_2D(char** tab, int n, int m){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            printf("%c", tab[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void taille_fichier(const char* nomFichier, int* nbLig, int* nbCol){
    FILE* file = NULL;
    file = fopen(nomFichier,"r");
    int charac = 0;
    if(file != NULL){
        do {
            charac = getc(file);
            *nbCol += 1;
            if (charac == '\n') {
                *nbLig += 1;
            }
        } while (charac != EOF);
        fclose(file);
    }

}
```

tabCaracteres.txt :
`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`
`bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`
`ccccccccccc`

Comment: without the actual files to process, the problem cannot be reproduced.  Can you post `tabCaracteres.txt`?

Comment: No there is nothing else, I created the project with CLION and I'm running on macos maybe it is related somehow ?

Comment: Is `CLION` just an IDE?  What compiler are you using?

Comment: Are you perhaps running valgrind on CLion instead of your program? What command line are you using to run valgrind?

Comment: I doubt it's your problem, but you should really check the return of `malloc()` (or function that return result of `malloc()`

Comment: I posted tabCaractere.txt

Comment: CLION is an IDE, I used the makefile CLION has generated to compile

Comment: I used these command to run valgrind : valgrind --leak-check=full ./TP2

Comment: ./TP2 is the executable generated by the make file (TP2 is the name of the project)

Comment: On a Mac, the startup code leaks a lot of memory.  Get a longer stack trace back (there's an option for it; it default to 12 levels, which is what you're seeing) and see whether `main` figures in it.  If not, the problem is not yours — you can add an extra suppression to your Valgrind system.  There are Q&A on SO about adding suppressions to Valgrind for macOS.

Comment: I stopped trying to use valgrind on my Mac. Instead I run a linux vm in fusion and share the source with that VM. Then I compile within the linux vm and run valgrind locally there. That workflow hasn't failed me even after many years. And I build the code for mac, windows, and linux.

Comment: See [Valgrind shows memory leak with empty main without including headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893494/valgrind-shows-memory-leak-with-empty-main-without-including-headers) for one example; [Is my Valgrind installation broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527113/is-my-valgrind-installation-broken) for another.

Comment: Also which versions of Valgrind and macOS is this with?